# How to open multiple files at the same time with geany in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, geany

I'm having a weird problem when i try to open multiple files in geany with a batch script.

The script is simple going in the folders i gave him as a list, and in each folder it'll open the Makefile here with geany. That is working; however, it'll first open the first Makefile, and then wait until i close the window to open the second one, and so on. 
It'll open the next Makefile in another tab, so at the end i still have all my makefiles opened, but i need to close the window between each one and i have a lot to open (that's why i made a script -_- )

Has anyone an idea on how to correct this weird behavior?

I made it in Linux with geany: it works well.
I made it in Windows with notepad: it works well.
But windows with geany doesn't work as i want it to do.

I've also tried using the command `start`, but it'll ask me with which prog i want to open the files and then do nothing at all.

Here is my script, a bit simplified:

```
rem set prog="C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe 
set prog="C:\Program Files\Geany\bin\geany.exe
set FOLDERLIST="Some Folders Names Separate ByASpace"

for /d %%C in (%FOLDERLIST%) do (
    cd %%~C 
    %prog% Makefile
    cd ..
)
```

So i want it to open all the files at once, without having to close the window between each. As you can see i have a rem line with notepad as prog, and this one is working as expected; geany isn't. But again, i made it in Linux with geany and it does open all files at once.

Comment: Well, your `for` loop will iterate once only and return `Some Folders Names Separate ByASpace` in `%%~C` due to your quotation in `set`; change this to `set "FOLDERLIST=Some Folders Names Separate ByASpace"` (note the opening quote; also for the other `set` statements), so the quotes do no longer become part of the variable value themselves, or, if one of the list items might contain spaces or other special characters on its own, do `set FOLDERLIST="Some" "Folders" "Names" "Separate" "By A Space"`...

Comment: Moreover, replace `cd %%~C` (which should read `cd /D "%%~C"`) and `cd ..` by [`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)`"%%~C"` and [`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html), respectively...

Comment: my bad, the quotes were correctly set as you said in my code. And for the `cd`...since it is working now, i would like to know in which way `push`and `popd` are better.

Comment: `pushd` stores the current working directory and changes to the new one, and `popd` returns to the original one then, so these commands are made for the purpose of intermittently change the directory; but you can use `cd` as well if you like...

Answer (score -1):

I found a working answer within this question : [SuperUser: Execute command line in background](https://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background)

So, i've found out that, when geany is open and i launch my batch script, it works perfectly. Then i tried to open geany in the batch script before opening all files, but it didn't work. Then, with some advice, i tried to open it like a deamon. And that's how the previously cited answer helped.

Here is the result:

```
rem set prog="C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe 
set prog="C:\Program Files\Geany\bin\geany.exe
set FOLDERLIST="Some Folders Names Separate ByASpace"

for /d %%C in (%FOLDERLIST%) do (
    cd %%~C 
    start "" %prog% Makefile
    cd ..
)
```

It seems that `start ""` launch the file in the background and so let the script going on and open the others files.

PS: Note that `start /B` without the `""`, also given as an answer, does not work for me since it's asking me with which prog i want to open the files.